# Наследование в Backbone локальные свойства

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Есть базовый класс

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    config:{
       rows:[]
    },
    initizalize: function(){
        this.Init();
        this.render();
    },
    AddSection: function(name){
        this.rows.push({header: name, body: {...}});
    }
}
```

Есть несколько потомков

```
var ChildOne = BaseView.extend({
    Init: function(){
        this.AddSection("Первый этаж");
        this.AddSection("Второй этаж"); 
    }
});

var ChildTwo = BaseView.extend({
    Init: function(){
        this.AddSection("Настройки wifi");
        this.AddSection("Настройки ethernet"); 
    }
});
```

Проблема в том, что у каждого экземпляра, одна и таже переменная `this.config`.

```
 var one = new ChildOne({el: '#one'});
 var two = new ChildTwo({el: '#two'});
```

`two.config.row`  будет содержать уже четыре элемента, как мне сделать свойство `this.config` локальным для каждого экземпляра?

Comment: DmitriySimushev, Пожалуй, использовать JSON оказалось плохим подходом при конвертировании он теряет колбеки, передаваемые в хеш. Использую _.isObject(copy_obj) {$.extend(true, {}, copy_obj) }

Comment: @JK_Action, это как-раз было очевидно. `JSON.stringify` убивает все методы. И не очень здорово обращается с объектами `Date`. Однако по скорости `JSON.stringify` + `JSON.parse` может оказаться существенно быстрее чем `$.extend(true,...`. Тут я был не прав

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дефолтные значения переменных:

```
var default_props = {
    config: {

        rows:[],
    },
    sec_count: 0,
    some_props2: [{}, ...{}]
    //...
};
```

Базовый класс

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //такой подход позволяет внедрять "статические" свойства только для чтения
    //или же если это "Финальный" класс - не планиурется дальнейшего наследования
    name: 'BaseView', 
    initialize: function(){
        var self = this;
        //инициализаия локальных свойств 
        //копируем дефолтные значения полностью
        _.mapObject(default_props, function(value, key){
        // =Сработает, если не передавать в хэш колбеки и undefined значения
        //JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
        if (_.isObject(value)){
            value = $.extend(true, {}, value);
        }
        self[key] = value;
        });
        this.Init(arguments);
        this.render(); 
        //или в дочернем объявить 
        //initizialize: function(){
        //    BaseView.prototype.initizialize.apply(this, arguments);
        //    ... инициализация
        //    this.render();
        //}
    },
    AddSection: function(cfg){
        cfg.body = { id: 'section' + this.sec_count}
        this.sec_count++;
        this.config.rows.push(cfg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Использовать `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)` очень уж не эффективно ;)

Comment: Не нашел лучшего способа глубокого копирования http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Answer (score 1):

В JavaScript массивы и объекты передаются и присваиваются *по ссылке*. Например, вот такое поведение является штатным:

```
var a = [1,2];
var b = a;

b.push(3);
console.log(a.join(',')); // выведет "1,2,3"
```

В тоже время, `Backbone.View.extend` использует *поверхностное копирование* для свойств объекта, переданного в качестве аргумента. Это и приводит к наблюдаемому вами эффекту.

Для решения проблемы, вам нужно создавать новый экземпляр массива и помещать его в `config.rows` при каждом создании экземпляра `BaseView`. Это можно сделать, например, так:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    config:{
        // Значение, задаваемое здесь будет обновлено в конструкторе
        // модели. Можете оставить его здесь "как есть" (полезно для 
        // документации) или же заменить значение на null (чтобы не
        // было соблазна добавлять поля по умолчанию)
        rows:[]
    },
    initizalize: function(){
        // Каждый экземпляр BaseView использует свой собственный массив
        // строк.
        this.config.rows = [];

        this.Init();
        this.render();
    },
    AddSection: function(name){
        this.rows.push({header: name, body: {...}});
    }
}
```

**UPD**:

Если в объекте `configs` будет несколько свойств-массивов (объектов) или каждый из этих объектов будет иметь существенные значения по умолчанию,
вы можете использовать в конструкторе *глубокое копирование* вместо простого присваивания значений по-умолчанию.

Comment: Если свойство будет сложным объектом( с большим уровнем вложенности) и свойств будет много, придется много писать руками. Кроме того не хочется терять механизм дефолтных значений.

Comment: @JK_Action, кончено, можно использовать какой-то механизм глубокого копирования в конструкторе вида. Но в текущей постановке вопроса это, как мне кажется, несколько избыточно.

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой вариант решения:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initizalize: function(){
        this.Init();
        this.render();
    },
    AddSection: function(name){
        this.rows.push({header: name, body: {...}});
    },
    getConfig: function() {
        return {
            rows:[]
        };
    }
});
var ChildOne = BaseView.extend({
    config: this.getConfig(),
    Init: function(){
        this.AddSection("Первый этаж");
        this.AddSection("Второй этаж"); 
    }
});

var ChildTwo = BaseView.extend({
    config: this.getConfig(),
    Init: function(){
        this.AddSection("Настройки wifi");
        this.AddSection("Настройки ethernet"); 
    }
});
```

Вызов метода getConfig() возвращает уникальные объекты, т.к. объекты созданные с помощью литералов являются уникальными.

Проверка:

```
var one = new ChildOne();
var two = new ChildTwo();
one.config.asd = "asd";
console.log(two.config.asd); // undefined
```

Comment: Открою вам маленькую тайну: в вашем примере все экземпляры `ChildOne` будут использовать один и тот же объект `congig`. Тоже самое справедливо и для экземпляров `ChildTwo`

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Вы не правы, проверка показывает обратное

Comment: Мне жаль, но вы не правы. 1. `config: this.getConfig()` не будет работать так, как вы того ожидаете. 2. Вы не внимательно причитали мой комментарий: все экземпляры **`ChildOne`** будут использовать один и тот же объект `config`. Пруф: http://jsfiddle.net/xeuoau1w/

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Ваш пример верный, только автор создает 2 экземпляра от разных конструкторов(ChildOne и ChildTwo). А у Вас создается 2 экземпляра от одного конструктора.